# MPI_File_open hangs

Tags: mpi, mpi-io

I suspect that I don't give the file path correctly - I am not a linux guy so I don't know what may be wrong really - code :

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // ...
    char *filename = argv[3];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    const int rank = get_rank();
    if (!rank) printf("%s\n", argv[3]); // /home/users1/stdxx/public_html/grid.txt
    // ...
    MPI_File * fh;
    if (!rank) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", rank); // I see this : 0
        if (MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, filename, MPI_MODE_RDONLY, 
                                            MPI_INFO_NULL, fh) != MPI_SUCCESS) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s\n", filename); // never seen
        }
    // rest runs fine if I comment out the MPI_File_open call
    }


int get_rank() {
    int rank = -1;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    return rank;
}
```

hangs even if I give an invalid path
If I comment out the  `if (!rank)` it crashes with :

```
rank 6 in job 54  linux21_60559   caused collective abort of all ranks
  exit status of rank 6: killed by signal 11 
rank 8 in job 54  linux21_60559   caused collective abort of all ranks
  exit status of rank 8: killed by signal 11 
rank 5 in job 54  linux21_60559   caused collective abort of all ranks
  exit status of rank 5: killed by signal 9 
rank 4 in job 54  linux21_60559   caused collective abort of all ranks
  exit status of rank 4: killed by signal 11 
rank 2 in job 54  linux21_60559   caused collective abort of all ranks
  exit status of rank 2: killed by signal 9 
rank 1 in job 54  linux21_60559   caused collective abort of all ranks
  exit status of rank 1: killed by signal 9
```

If on the other hand I give it a path of the form  `sftp://stdxxxxx@linux11.di.uoa.gr/home/users1/stdxxxxx/public_html/grid.txt` it goes its merry way to `Cannot open file sftp://stdxxxxx@linux11.di.uoa.gr/home/users1/stdxxxxx/public_html/grid.txt`

*Why ?*

Running this remotely via netbeans in a cluster of linux machines. Command :

> /usr/local/mpich2/bin/mpiexec -machinefile machines -np 9 "${OUTPUT_PATH}" 84 9 /home/users1/stdxxxxx/public_html/grid.txt

`"${OUTPUT_PATH}"` is the executable

`mpirun --version` or `mpiexec --version` result in `invalid "local" arg: --version`

EDIT :

```
mpicc -v
mpicc for 1.1.1p1
Using built-in specs.
Target: i486-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,treelang --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --enable-nls --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2 --program-suffix=-4.2 --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --enable-mpfr --enable-targets=all --enable-checking=release --build=i486-linux-gnu --host=i486-linux-gnu --target=i486-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4)
```

Comment: `MPI_File_open` is a collective routine and all ranks in the specified communicator must call it. You're limiting the call to only `rank == 0`, therefore it hangs.

Comment: @Hristo : this solves my last doubts - thanks - any comments on the  way to construct those filenames ? You may post them as an answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Segmentation fault while using MPI\_File\_open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736136/segmentation-fault-while-using-mpi-file-open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the winner is :

```c
MPI_File * fh = malloc(sizeof * fh);
```

argghh - the simple joys of C

Still interested in why it does not crash when I give it the `sftp:` uris (I guess because it never gets to the pointer part)  - and *what is the right way to construct the filename*<sup>1</sup> - so I am not accepting my answer yet.

<sup>1</sup> : from [here](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_File_open.html) :

> The format for specifying the file name in the filename argument is implementation dependent and must be documented by the implementation.

and

> On some implementations of MPI, the file namespace may not be identical from all processes of all applications. For example, "c:\tmp\foo" may denote different files on different processes, or a single file may have many names, dependent on process location. The user is responsible for ensuring that a single file is referenced by the filename argument, as it may be impossible for an implementation to detect this type of namespace error.